# Does Visual Studio 2015 allow normal C++ project to be compiled with GCC?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, visual-studio-2015

Title says it all really, I keep reading odd snippets saying Visual Studio 2015 contains GCC but can you create a normal C++ project and compile it using GCC?

Comment: _"I keep reading odd snippets ..."_ Any links, that we can check validity? IIRC visual studio never came with a GCC toolchain out of the box. May be you're able to change the toolchain with the latest VS 2015, but I'm pretty sure you have to install the alternative toolchains separately, if this feature exists.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ This link seems to suggest it is available; but possibly only when targetting native Android: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/04/29/what-s-new-with-c-cross-platform-development-with-vs-2015-rc.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I believe that Visual Studio 2015 comes with a proprietary compiler from Microsoft and does not use GCC. However, if you are looking for a C/C++ IDE that uses GCC as the default toolchain, Code blocks is a wonderful option. It's also built for Linux, Mac, and Windows. [This is their site.](http://www.codeblocks.org/)

Comment: MS Windows advice: though you should probably use [mingw-w64's gcc](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/) (this is the 32bit link) rather then the default that codeblocks ships with as it is missing some of the newer features (it's GCC 4.7 vs mingw-w64 GCC 5.2)

Comment: I wanted to use the debugging capabilities of VS though as it is extremely good.....

Comment: I wanted to use the debugging capabilities of VS though as it is extremely good.....

Comment: @user997112 What capabilities exactly?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know,there's no official toolchain in VS[version] to code directly target *gcc/g++.

Your best bet in this scenario is either port the code, use something like Wine.

That being said, I was slightly confused by the question, as far as the VS Project being compiled by gcc, doubt it. VS uses a "Solution", so you should probably start by porting the "Makefile".?